# Trying to decode long valid Json, getting errors in PHP/ZEND

Tags: php, json, zend-framework

I am trying to parse a very large Json string, and I am getting errors when I try using multiple methods.

When I use PHP json_decode(); I get a stack overflow error, so I decided to try the ZEND_Json decode(), which gives me a Syntax Error Exception.

When I put this string into an online "Json decoder", it says it is valid, so I am not sure if something is wrong with the format or if it is too long? If so, is there a library that can handle very large json strings? Here is the Json I am trying to decode, Thanks!:

http://pastebin.com/Z0gjAaYx

Comment: try [json_last_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)

Comment: @MarcB I have done this, and it tells me that there is a JSON_ERROR_DEPTH error. Is there a parser that has a larger stack?

Comment: probably, but I've never had to use anything other than the one built into PHP, and that one DOES have an optional depth control parameter. defaults to 512. try that one instead of zend's and see what happens.